# How to make ROC from raw data?

Tags: r

I am testing multiple detectors, have calculated the MCC score but am trying to see if I can also make ROC curves from the data

The data looks like this (where D is the detection, R is the true result, 1/0 is yes/no):

```
data.frame(D1 = c(0,1,1,1,0),
           D2 = c(0,0,1,1,0),
           D3 = c(0,0,0,1,1),
           R = c(0,1,1,0,0))
```

Is there a simple way to make ROC curves from this data setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

You ideally should use a class prediction that hasn't been rounded to integers, ie `0.789` instead of `1`

The whole point with ROC is to investigate how prediction performance changes with classification threshold. That's not really possible if you have already done the thresholding.